# Android - error: Default constructor not found for type

Tags: c#, android

error: System.MissingMethodException: 'Default constructor not found for type ProjectName.Library.IImageCropperWrapper'

getting an eror on line:

```
 DependencyService.Get<IImageCropperWrapper>().ShowFromFile(this, imageFile);
```

i already have a constructor so no idea why im getting this error.

code where error is occurring

```
 [assembly: Dependency(typeof(IImageCropperWrapper))]
namespace ProjectName.Library
{
   public  class ImageCropper
    {
        public static ImageCropper Current { get; set; }
        ...

        public ImageCropper()
        {
            Current = this;
        }
        
        public async void Show(Page page, string imageFile = null)
        {
          //take picture code
                file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    PhotoSize = ImageSize,
                    CompressionQuality = ImageCompressionQuality,
                });
               imageFile = file.Path;

           //error here
           DependencyService.Get<IImageCropperWrapper>().ShowFromFile(this, imageFile);
        }
    }
}
```

below i have a interface of imagecropper class

```
namespace ProjectName.Library
{
    public interface IImageCropperWrapper
    {
        void ShowFromFile(ImageCropper imageCropper, string imageFile);

        byte[] GetBytes(string imageFile);
    }
}
```

In my View Class, I am calling ImageCropper class like

```
async void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           new ImageCropper()
                {
                    Success = (imageFile) =>
                    {
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            ImagePage1.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                        });
                    }
                }.Show(this);
}
```

Comment: Error States the container tries to instantiate an interface rather than the implementation.

Comment: aw i see. do have any idea how can i try to fix it? is issue in ImageCropper class?

Comment: How are you adding it to the container?

Comment: sorry which container? i'm new to this. I am calling ImageCropper() inside button click event. does that helps?

Comment: do you think issue can be with [assembly: Dependency(typeof(IImageCropperWrapper))]? or any hits regarding debugin this?

Comment: Assuming that you're following [this repo](https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms) notice how in [iOS.Platform](https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms/blob/master/ImageCropper/ImageCropper.iOS/Platform.cs)/[Android.Platform](https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms/blob/master/ImageCropper/ImageCropper.Android/Platform.cs) there's a call to [DependencyService.Register<I, Impl>()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.dependencyservice.register?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_DependencyService_Register__2).

Comment: This tells the DependencyService what's the actual type to instantiate when user asks for certain interface.